# Handling complex computation on a web app involving data from a database

Tags: sql, django, database, client

Just some background.

This question is to help my team and I make a decision on how to handle an app we are working on. Currently the application is hosted locally in ASP.NET C# and the complex calculations that are done are handled in SQL as a stored procedure. The data is pulled into queries and the server will handle all the calculations and return a recordset which is written to a table and the front end can access that table.

So moving forward, we're thinking of moving the application to the web with Django and deciding how to handle the server side of things. So what we really wanted to understand is, how do others handle situations like these? Do we continue with the same idea and build a SQL server and do the same thing or is there a better way to solve this problem? We want to the user to be able to kick the calculations off and do other things while it runs in the background. The user shouldn't have to sit on the page because these calculation can take an hour or more depending on the complexity. We'd appreciate the thought and ideas.

Thank you so much.

Comment: "We want to the user to be able to kick the calculations off and do other things while it runs in the background." - this is the key, so what you can do? Store user requests on the server and process it in the background...

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what Celery does. And the integration with Django is very easy. Read about it.

Comment: Thank Paul. I'll read about this! It definitely looks like something we could use. Appreciate the advice.